# Go JS library - How to zoom in when clicked on any node in graph

Tags: gojs

I am using GO JS library & wanted to know how to zoom-in when clicked on any particular node in GO JS.
As of now my diagram is using `"initialAutoScale: go.Diagram.Uniform"`.

I have reference of scaling [here](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/initialView.html), but its not more clear.
Can anyone provide any examples how to zoom based on click of node & wanna see that particular node when graph is huge with approx 50+ nodes connected.

When Graph is small below is screenshot :
[image]

Once the graph expands in any direction, the nodes goes smaller & smaller to fit & i want auto scale & zoom scale to be same as above just scroll horizontally if required.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "zoom in ... on any particular node"?  Can you show small screenshots for before and after?

Comment: @WalterNorthwoods Apologies for delays, please find my updated post.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the **Diagram.autoScale** property.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

1. Register for `selectionChanged` event on your `myDiagram.nodeTemplate`.
2. On your event-handling method, invoke these lines and pass the selected node.

   ```
   myDiagram.commandHandler.resetZoom();
   myDiagram.commandHandler.scrollToPart(selectedNode);
   ```